# Postgres - create table but name is current month

Tags: postgresql

I want to be able to create a new table which contains the current month.

Basically I've going to create a python script that each month will automatically load a lots of crime data, this python script will create a new table called crime_data (this is the easy bit). I then want to run a second script that will create a new table with a name which is date-stamped with the system-date month and filter out elements of the original crime_data.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is the purpose of such table?

Comment: Do you intend to keep more than a year worth  of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. Try creating PL/pgSQL function like that:

```
BEGIN

EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE crime_data_'||to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'Month')||' AS
SELECT *
FROM crime_data cd
WHERE date_part(''month'', cd.date) = date_part(''month'', CURRENT_DATE)';

END;
```

You need to adapt it for your needs, but idea is to form the query as a string and `EXECUTE` it.

Details here: [`CREATE TABLE AS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html) [`to_char()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) [`date_part`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html)

UPD It may be better to create a `VIEW` with the data you need instead of a table:

```
EXECUTE 'CREATE VIEW crime_data_'||to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'Month')||' AS
SELECT *
FROM crime_data cd
WHERE date_part(''month'', cd.date) = date_part(''month'', CURRENT_DATE)';
```

You will be able to `SELECT` from this `VIEW` as it was table and you wont need to keep duplicated data. Details here: [`CREATE VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html).

UPD2 To test this thing:

1) do:

```
SELECT 'CREATE TABLE crime_data_'||to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'Month')||' AS
        SELECT *
        FROM crime_data cd
        WHERE date_part(''month'', cd.date) = date_part(''month'', CURRENT_DATE)'
```

2) Take the result of this `SELECT` and run it as a regular statement.

PL/pgSQL `EXECUTE` statement does exactly this two things. 1 - forms the string. 2 - executes it as statement.

Comment: So i've just tried to do this in the first instance to get the statement right CREATE TABLE crime_data_||to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'Month')|| AS SELECT * FROM crime_data but get an error message at ||. Creating a view isnt an option as the original crime data will be dropped.

Comment: @Med You cant concat (|| operator) directly in the `CREATE TABLE` statement. See my update.

Comment: So I ran UPD2 1) and I see a ?Column text? with a "CREATE TABLE crime_data_December as" statement but then i'm not following how I then take the result of this select statement and run it.  I use psycopg2 as the engine (if thats the correct word) to run my sql statements via python, so i dont understand how I can take UPD2 2) as an automatic 'thingy!?' process.

Comment: @Med UPD2 is for testing purposes. For real automatic thingy you will need to create the PL/pgSQL function in you DB schema with `EXECUTE ...` inside the function body.

Comment: @Med [Here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) you can read, how to create a function.

Comment: arr, your talking about functions! This is a very new and mystical world of Postgres that I've not explored yet. Do you know of a good 101 guide to functions to bring me up to speed so that I understand where your coming from?

Comment: @Med The best guide a know for postgresql function is the postgresql official manual. It is really clear and good. Here it is: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html

Comment: @Med Read [this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) chapter for details about PL/pgSQL.

Comment: @Med And I recommend you to a get GUI tool to work with the database. Like the default [PgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/). It will speed up the work with DB and make your life easier.